# Is there a simple method for square root of big.Rat?

Tags: go, math

**I need to find the square root of a big.Rat.** Is there a way to do it without losing (already existing) accuracy?

For example, I could convert the numerator and denominator into floats, get the square root, and then convert it back...

```
func ratSquareRoot(num *big.Rat) *big.Rat {
    f, exact := num.Float64() //Yuck! Floats!
    squareRoot := math.Sqrt(f)
    var accuracy int64 = 10 ^ 15 //Significant digits of precision for float64
    return big.NewRat(int64(squareRoot*float64(accuracy)), accuracy) 
    // ^ This is now totally worthless. And also probably not simplified very well.
```

}

...but that would eliminate all of the accuracy of using a rational. **Is there a better way of doing this?**

Comment: Your accuracy `10 ^ 15` is probably intended to be 10 to the power of 15, but it's actually 10 xor 15 = 5.

Comment: In the general case, roots are not rational numbers. What type would you have them be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `big.Float` type has a `.Sqrt(x)` operation, and handles defining explicitly the precision you aim for. I'd try to use that and convert the result back to a `Rat` with the same operations in your question, only manipulating `big.Int` values.

```
    r := big.NewRat(1, 3)

    var x big.Float
    x.SetPrec(30) // I didn't figure out the 'Prec' part correctly, read the docs more carefully than I did and experiement
    x.SetRat(r)

    var s big.Float
    s.SetPrec(15)
    s.Sqrt(&x)

    r, _ = s.Rat(nil)
    fmt.Println(x.String(), s.String())
    fmt.Println(r.String(), float64(18919)/float64(32768))
```

[playground](https://go.dev/play/p/UKnhYD1xiln)